# DropDownList quantidade Itens

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Bom dia, estou utilizando `dropdownlist` no `asp.net` para carregar alguns dados vindo do banco, porém eu não sei a quantidade que irá ser mostrada, pois depende do preenchimento no banco.

Eu gostaria de mostrar somente uma certa quantidade de itens.

Por exemplo, se possuir 29 registros, quero mostrar somente os 5 primeiros e após isso mostrar barra de rolagem, sempre com 5 registros.

Porém de toda forma que tento não consigo, existe alguma forma de limitar a quantidade de itens do `dropdownlist` que é preenchido pelo banco de dados?

**Dropdownlist:**

```html
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cbfuncionario" runat="server" style = "overflow-y: scroll"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**e aqui carrego o dropdownlist:**

```html
  public void CarregaFuncionario()
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            comando.Connection = clsdb.AbreBanco();
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.CommandText = "select pessoa.id,nome FROM [pessoa] inner join classificacoes on classificacoes.id = pessoa.classificacao_id where estado <> 'Inativo' and estado <> 'Excluido' and classificacoes.tipo = '1' order by pessoa.nome ASC";

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = comando;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);


            cbfuncionario.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            cbfuncionario.DataTextField = "nome";
            cbfuncionario.DataValueField = "id";
            cbfuncionario.DataBind();
           
        }
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código?

Comment: Alterei a pergunta incluindo o código. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando position:absolute; e this.size, é possivel escolher a quantidade de items(10 no exemplo)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cbfuncionario" onclick="this.size=1;" onMouseOver="this.size=10;" onMouseOut="this.size=1;" runat="server" style = "position:absolute;"></asp:DropDownList>
```

[Creditos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550063/how-to-limit-the-visible-items-of-dropdownlist-which-is-populated-by-dataset)

Comment: Também não de Leo, ele fica do tamanho normal, e não abre na quantidade, você vai descendo direto em uma linha só, não expande.

Comment: Leo, na verdade funcionou sim, pois havia um css por trás, e retirei, e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Creio que isso resolva seu problema, caso queira mostrar mais itens altere a altura do seu item **HEIGHT**

```
<style type="text/css">
 .scrollable{
   overflow: auto;
   width: 70px; 
   height: 80px; /
   border: 1px silver solid;
 }
 .scrollable select{
   border: none;
 }
</style>
```

E seu código HTML fica assim

```
<div class="scrollable">
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cbfuncionario" runat="server" style = "overflow-y: scroll"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, porém continua mostrando a quantidade de itens da página, não foi alterado para mostrar somente alguns itens, mudou somente a design do dropdown, mas ao abrir pra mostrar, continua mostrando todos de uma vez.